# To MultiThread or not to MultiThread?

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-4.0

Lets say a FIFO(*one which is thread safe*) has items being added to it ( *we dont care how*)

```
|__|  |
|  |  |
|__|  |
|  |  |
|__|  V
| d|
|__|
| c|
|__|
| b|
|__|
| a|
```

Now lets say the items (one by one) should be inserted to  *another* concurrent collection .

The rate of data  insertion is *dynamic*.

I want to do it in the fastest way. ( transfer all the elements from the `Fifo` to the `collection`).

But I'm having a conflict  :

- I could use *one* thread to pull out items from the `Fifo` and insert them into the `collection`. but then I wont be using cores  / other threads which can help me.
- I could use several consumer threads to take items from `Fifo` , but then maybe the internal locking on the `Fifo` (when reading), and the internal locking on the `collection`(when writing) will eventually reduce performance.

I mean , there will be a situation where if I have enormousness consumer threads , there will be also enormousness  internal locking with the fifo / collection , *plus* many many context switching

*How* can I approach this kind of problem the right way?  What is the guideline ?

Comment: have you considered using ConcurrentBag<T> ?

Comment: @daryal The Whole question is regarding thread safe collection.

Comment: I do not see how is this question is related to exactly .NET. The problem may attract more users and result in more interesting discussion if all developers working with multithreading would look into it.

Comment: Im talking about concurrent collections from .net framework. maybe it is working in another way in construct to java. or maybe there is another solution in .net which can solve this. **the .net tag should be there**.

Comment: @Audrius Meškauskas: On the other hand, the C# tag is the most popular, so you're technically reducing the question's potential audience by removing the tag.

Comment: @AudriusMeškauskas why did you remove the tag ? please don't do that again.Im looking for a solution/alternatives from the .net world.

Comment: Just to be clear - you are just extracting object references from the queue and adding them to the collection, right?

Comment: @MartinJames yes. ( but dont tell me to insert straight to the collection :-) )

Comment: @RoyiNamir - oh, I wasn't going to suggest that!  I will suggest that one thread is the best solution - the amount of actual work involved in each pop/insert is not worth the overhead of multiple pop/insert threads.

Comment: What's the problem with single threading?  Moving objects between collections is normally a very fast operation... identify your bottlenecks and then address them.  Shooting in the dark is just going to break something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple threads contending for the same concurrent collection will always be a bottleneck situation. The problem usually gets worse the more threads you have, but the rate of degradation depends on the locking mechanisms. I expect that the new concurrent collections in .NET 4.0 are lock-free, or at least use non-blocking locks, so they should be contention-friendly to a certain degree.

Since the question seems to be open-ended, I suggest that you simply experiment with various numbers of threads and find a balance between the fifo contention and the throughput you want to achieve.

Comment: Not lock free (at least `ConcurrentBag`/`ConcurrentDictionary` aren't) they use "intelligent" locking - `ConcurrentQueue` seems to be using `SpinWait` to block

Comment: @mlorbetske: As long as they don't use blocking locks they're still rather efficient. And certainly the style of locking depends on the access patterns. Hashtable-like structures will always use different locking than queues, but we're talking about fifo here.

Comment: 100% agree, was just going for the clarification, a lock-free collection would be `CAS` only or `CAS` + `SpinWait` (or some other caller-thread-only blocking mechanism). `ConcurrentBag`/`ConcurrentDictionary` still use `Monitor` for locking but do it only in the cases where required. The alternative to both approaches, of course, being to take collection level locks at any mutation/state inspection - and yes, the concurrent collections in .Net 4 are way better than that.

Comment: Some lock free collections in java have a throughput which improves almost linearly with the number of threads (up to # processors of course). I would expect .net to have something similar.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing minimal processing between the collections, use only one thread. If you have multiple destination collections,then you might want to use multiple threads. Or if the data structures at both ends are complex structures with advanced locking , which actually support multithreaded insertion instead of just locking stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider using Task Parallel Library (TPL) for this.

You could keep a queue and when it has items let the parallel framework do all the heavy lifting for you. No need to handle your own thread pool with all the hairy code managing threads.

Must confess I have not done this myself as of yet, but if I was in your situation I would refresh my TPL skillz and start thinking in terms of Task rather than thread x.

Answer (score 0):

This could be done by several non interacting threads if we have access to the internals of both collections. For instance, if that stack is a linked list of known size, the two threads could process it from the both ends till they meet, and they could build a new linked list one appending elements to the tail and another to the head.

From the other side, if the stack is also an array, probably nothing can be faster than some analog of memcpy on a single thread.